# Session ID failing when screen duplicated

Tags: java, jsp, session-state, hidden-field, sessionid

I have had to add a unique session ID to an application to prevent cross site request forgery.
To do so I've implemented a unique session ID when a session starts. This session ID is stored both in session and on every page of the application (on a JSP as a hidden value). I've created a method which then compares the two, if they are not the same an error screen appears. This all works fine. My issue is whenever I copy the URL and paste it to create a new window or tab the session ID on the page is NULL and causes the error page to flag. Am I missing something really easy here?

Any help or pointers is greatly appropriated

Comment: It seems like the session ID generated in your page depends on the session ID posted by a prior request, and not on the session ID stored on server side. Can you post the code that writes the session ID to the hidden field?

Comment: The session ID is created and added as an attribute, on each jsp this code is called:
'HttpSession thisSession = request.getSession();
String sessionID = thisSession.getAttribute("SESSIONID).toString();'

Comment: I think i know what you mean though. It may be the value i am comparing to the server side value. I'll have a look into that.
Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to prevent session hijacking, you should store the IP and user-agent in the session and check on each request that the ones in the request match those in the session. Just what you're doing will not be enough.

Comment: Beware about ip-based session id's, as if someone is trying to view your site from a NAT based network without the proper ip rewrites everyone in that network will be identified as the same session.